# How do you use an input number to extract rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting rows based on input of a column header and a value.
For example, to extract data rows for all 'bmw' under 'company.

I can do this under strings (e.g. bmw, mercedes under 'company') but not numbers (e.g. '111' under horsepower).

I tried to change numbers like '111' to string but to no avail.

Sorry for the bad formatting, learning the platform.

Any help is appreciated!

Part of my data is:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

column1_title = input("Hi! Please enter the first column name you are searching for: ")
column1_title = column1_title.lower()

def extract(column_check):
    if np.any(column_check == df.columns):
        column1_value = input("Thank you. Please enter the value you are looking for under this name: ")
        column1_value = str(column1_value.lower())

        if np.any(column1_value == df[column_check]):
            print("You have entered:", column1_value) #feedback.
            print(df.loc[df[column_check] == column1_value]) #M2

    elif column_check.lower() == "exit":
            print("Thank you. Goodbye.")

extract(column1_title)
```

Comment: `print(df.loc[df[column_check].astype(str) == column1_value])`

Comment: On a side note - `if np.any(column_check == df.columns)` can be `if column_check in df`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are making the user input a `string` type, you should convert any `Series` you are checking to a string type by using the `.astype(str)` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

column1_title = input("Hi! Please enter the first column name you are searching for: ")
column1_title = column1_title.lower()

def extract(column_check):
    if np.any(column_check == df.columns):
        column1_value = input("Thank you. Please enter the value you are looking for under this name: ")
        column1_value = str(column1_value.lower())

        ## change this block
        if np.any(column1_value == df[column_check].astype(str)):
            print("You have entered:", column1_value) #feedback.
            print(df.loc[df[column_check].astype(str) == column1_value]) #M2

    elif column_check.lower() == "exit":
            print("Thank you. Goodbye.")

extract(column1_title)
```

Example output from the command line:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':['a','b']})
>>> extract('a')
Thank you. Please enter the value you are looking for under this name: 1
You have entered: 1
   a  b
0  1  a
```

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that other people know what worked

Comment: Derek, I noticed that if I entered Horsepower > 111.0, which is a float, it cannot process even though changed to String. What can I do?

Comment: @Scoutboy84 I would recommend checking the datatype of what the user is entering (float, string, int) and having a separate condition for each case. you can also check the datatype of the column that the user is trying to access. you'll need to think of all of the edge cases and debug your program — this is what programming is about!

Comment: Thanks, I know why. String "111.0" is not the same as String "111" to Python.